# add total SUM of column in html table

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table that I want to add a total of the price column.

I have done this with javascript, however, I'm having an issue where it's not adding the value after a decimal point e.g. 5.50

here is my js code

```
var tds = document.getElementById('quote').getElementsByClassName('tprice');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
  
var total = sum.toFixed(2);

document.getElementById('totalprice').innerHTML += "£" + total;
```

Comment: `parseInt` stands for "parse integer". You probably want `parseFloat`.

Comment: See MDN JavaScript documentation: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) vs. [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Floating points have decimal points. Integers have not.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, using parseFloat worked!

Answer (score 2):

Your script can benefit from a map and a reduce with casting to number rather than the parseInt you have which will remove all decimals

I use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) here instead of parseInt/Float

```js
let sum = 0;
const prices = [...document.querySelectorAll('#quote .tprice')]
  .map(td => isNaN(td.textContent) ? 0 : +td.textContent); // an array of numbers
if (prices.length) sum = prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b);   // reduced to a sum
document.getElementById('totalprice').innerHTML += "£" + sum.toFixed(2);
```

```html
<table id="quote">
  <tr>
    <td class="tprice">15.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tprice">16.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tprice">17.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tprice">18.50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="totalprice"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybee try change this line:

```
sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
```

to

```
var value = parseFloat(tds[i].innerHTML);
sum += isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
```

but better show example of HTML table with sample (NOT PRODUCTION!) data